# database access within .net .toLookup - will it produce a table lock?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, odp.net

I have the following code:

```
ILookup<string, costcenterdata> areas = p_data.CostcenterDatas.ToLookup(p => OracleDataProvider.GetAreaForClient(p_data.ClientID), p => p);
```

it takes acollection of pocos and generates a lookup. For determining the key it goes to an ORACLE table and performs a select foo from data where bar.
Nothing fancy. This is done in GetAreaFromClient which does open conncection, read, close connection with ODP.net. No Entity Framework or other newfangled stuff.

But sometimes it seems to produce a lock. the code above waits endlessly and in the end, we have to cancel the connection in the database.

Can it be tha the toLockup somehow produces a parallel access that may or may not produce this lock?

Comment: How large is the table?

Comment: I just checked the ,net sources. Seems that there is in fact a call to  a parallelQuery in toLookup. I guess this might be too much for the db access layer somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's locking/blocking is more akin to sql server's snapshot isolation, so there shouldn't be any blocking of a simple select.

Are you sure that method is only doing a select or that it's connection wasn't used for something else?

In any case a dba should be able to help you determine why the connection is blocked.  You could also try looking yourself if you have permissions with something like:

```
select 
   ao.object_name,
   ao.object_type,
   s.sid,
   s.username,
   s.status,
   s.osuser,
   s.machine,
   s.program,
   s.module,
   s.wait_time,
   s.seconds_in_wait,
   lo.inst_id,
   s.*, lo.*
from
   gv$locked_object lo ,
   gv$session s,
   all_objects ao
where
   s.sid = lo.session_id
and
   lo.object_id = ao.object_id
and s.username = 'connectionUserName';
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Unfortunately I can't really reproduce the error - I guess I will have to wait til lthe users do that for me